# I am unable to run calabash script in my console

Tags: calabash

path : C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files\Kerio\Outlook Connector (Offline Edition)\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;D:\Automation\android-sdk;D:\Automation\android-sdk\tools;D:\Automation\android-sdk\platform-tools

ANDROID_HOME : D:\Automation\android-sdk

JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0

C:\Users\nanda.kumar\Desktop\bbb>calabash-android console D:\Automation Tools\Calabash_Requirements\7.1.2com.
tesco.grocery.view-Aligned.apk

After the above step,I am getting the following error

Could not find an Android SDK please make sure it is installed.
You can read about how Calabash-Android is searching for an Android SDK and how you can help here:
https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md#prerequisites

Android SDK is installed and it is working fine with Robotium. I don't know what is wrong here. can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the following

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/env.rb

```
def self.path_if_android_home(path)
   path if path && File.exists?(File.join(path, 'platform-tools', adb_executable))
end
```

$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb must exist

It seems that in the new ANDROID SDK, it’s in the bin folder, so i just created a symlink “platform-tools” to the “bin” directory.

Hope this helps

Samir

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest including the path of android tools  in the environment variables in the drive where OS is installed(C drive) and reboot the machine. Let me know if this helps

ANDROID_TOOLS=C:\Automation\android-sdk\tools\
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=C:\Automation\android-sdk\platform-tools\

Answer (score 0):

Can you please set your android home on path as

%ANDROID_HOME%/platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%/tools the same applies with JAVA_HOME as well.So your path should look something like this

path : C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files\Kerio\Outlook Connector (Offline Edition)\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;**%JAVA_HOME\bin**;%ANT_HOME%\bin;**%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;**

Try this and see. Running adb should you the commands of android?

Regards,
Sai